# Copy folder frrom local machine to a server in linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos7

I am trying to copy a filled folder from my local machine to AWS server.
So, I used the following command, but was not working:

`scp -r IPADTEST.pem oafolder ec2-user@__________.compute.amazonaws.com:testfolder`

The error was:

```
ec2-user@_________.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

I am sure the IPADTEST.pem is working okay, because I can SSH from the same location:

```
$ ssh -i IPADTEST.pem  ec2-user@_____________.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Also, I can copy a file (not folder), for example I can copy `index.html`:

```
sudo scp -i IPADTEST.pem index.html ec2-user@______________.compute.amazonaws.com:testfolder/
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the SSH command you use to successfully connect to the same instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can copy a file (not folder)"? Are you using the exact same command, but `oafolder` is the name of a file? If so, please include that in your Question.

Comment: Thanks for your all advises and comments. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need "-i .pem".

Q: Have you tried `scp -r -i IPADTEST.pem oafolder ec2-user@__________.compute.amazonaws.com:testfolder`?